# deploying application to Openshift using jenkins DSL using private repositories

Tags: open-closed-principle

HiIs there any way to perform these:

1. Any ways is approved as long as it creates a container image and registers it in the Open shift private container registry.
2. Uses Jenkins DSL to deploy to Open Shift
3. In the Jenkins pipeline, ROKS team should create a build and deploy stage.